# Load balancing express app instances

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, load-balancing

This is my first load balancing question.

I have written a simple express app to figure out how load balancing works. Also I was taking a look at something like `docker`. If I had to use Nginx to load balance, should I be running 4 different express instances in 4 different docker containers and then load balance between them using Nginx where Nginx sits in its own container ?

Have I got it right? I am kind of confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provided an answer to a [similar post some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33089609/809866), but here's the important bits in a nutshell:

> Yes, it's possible to use Nginx to load balance requests between
>   different instances of your Node.js services. Each Node.js instance
>   could be running in a different Docker container.

You can then modify Nginx to load balance between the containers using for example the configuration file mentioned in the link above.

Nginx itself can perfectly run within a Docker container. For these kinds of setups, [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) can help you orchestrate the configuration such that you can start up all Nginx and Express containers with a simple command.

Comment: But how do you scale it up ? I mean ultimately multiple docker images are running on limited resource right ?

Comment: Typically you'll have one physical machine running multiple Docker containers. The amount of Docker images depends on many factors: type of application, configuration of the physical machine, container settings etc. For Node.js, one Docker container per CPU is what I would recommend. You can use the  [cpuset parameter](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpuset-constraint) in Docker to explicitly bind a container to a specific CPU. A great example is also available [here](http://agileek.github.io/docker/2014/08/06/docker-cpuset/). In general though, you want to experiment with this.

Comment: Thanks this was very useful :)